# PHPUnit\Framework\Error\Warning: ini_set(): Headers already sent. You cannot change the session module's ini settings at this time

Tags: phpunit, zend-framework3, php-7.2, zend-test

I'm following [zend's tutorial](https://docs.zendframework.com/tutorials/unit-testing/%22zend's%20tutorial%22) to use zend-test on my project, but I'm getting this [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9iqWh.png).

To build my project's base I did the biggest part of this [book](https://olegkrivtsov.github.io/using-zend-framework-3-book/html/en/toc.html).

I'm also using PHP 7.2.

When I search google I found a lot of people having trouble using PHP 7.2 with PHP Unit, but it looks like it's ok by now. Did zend-test also being update? If no, what can I do to use zend-test by now? If yes, how do I get the last version?

**EDIT**

After some test I found the problem, it is on the bootstrap function:

```
public function onBootstrap( MvcEvent $event ) {
    $application = $event->getApplication();
    $serviceManager = $application->getServiceManager();
    $sessionManager = $serviceManager->get(SessionManager::class);

    $eventManager = $event->getApplication()->getEventManager();
    $sharedEventManager = $eventManager->getSharedManager();
    // Registra o método fo event listener
    $sharedEventManager->attach(AbstractActionController::class,
            MvcEvent::EVENT_DISPATCH, [$this, 'onDispatch'], 100);

    // Caso a sessão não seja válida, esquece ela
    $this->forgetInvalidSession($sessionManager);
}
```

To be more specific, the problem starts at this line:

```
$sessionManager = $serviceManager->get(SessionManager::class);
```

**EDIT 2**

Removing that line e it's uses, it kind than work, but starts to give the same error in another module in a similar line:

```
$authService = $container->get(\Zend\Authentication\AuthenticationService::class);
```

Comment: ServiceManager is no longer available in this way. You should create yourself a Listener/Factory combination for the purpose that this `onBootstrap` function does and inject the dependencies required (just the `SessionManager`) into the Listener class. [Example in an answer of mine a few months ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52261931/zf3-dependency-injection-in-module-php/52265276#52265276)

Answer (score 2):

Use the [**`--stderr`**](https://docs.phpunit.de/en/9.6/textui.html) argument for `phpunit`.

```
phpunit YourTestFile.php  --stderr
```

From the documentation:

```
--stderr                    Write to STDERR instead of STDOUT
```

PHPUnit is writing its own output (for instance, I see: `"PHPUnit 8.5.2 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors."` whenever I run it).  This is considered STDOUT of the page in PHP, which, of course, means that "text has already been sent".  If you divert the output to STDERR, STDOUT will just be the output of the PHP file that you are testing.