# How to correctly configure listener?

Tags: unit-testing, phpunit, listener, zend-framework3

I have a problem with testing ZF3 app with listeners. Currently listeners attaches in module.php onBootsrtap like this

```
$eventManager = $event->getApplication()->getEventManager();       
$serviceManager->get(\App\Listener\OfferListener::class)->attach($eventManager);
```

Attach function in listener

```
public function attach(EventManagerInterface $events, $priority=1)
{
    $this->listeners[] = $events->getSharedManager()->attach('*', 'offerChange', [$this, 'onOfferChange']);
}
```

The problem is that listener initialized before testcontroller create mock objects. When calling

```
$this->getApplicationServiceLocator()
```

to configure ServiceManager for test in test controller, listener factory is calling and test fails because it depends on database mapper. 
Maybe this approach is bad. 
Could anyone help me please?

Comment: What you're looking for, [here you'll find](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52265276/1155833) :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
But its not exactly what i need. My solution is that listeners attaches at EVENT_DISPATCH event.So at bootstrap stubs are created and tests working fine.

Comment: Sure it's exactly that. In the `attach()` function you'll just have to attach to that event instead of the one provided in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is that listeners attaches at EVENT_DISPATCH event.So at bootstrap stubs are created and tests working fine